# Sitecore values -- Template > Standard Values > Branch > Item

Tags: templates, content-management-system, sitecore, branch

OK, here's the process I took...

1. create a new template "Mail Message"
2. create a "__Standard Values" item for the template
3. edit the "Subject" field in the standard values item: "Monthly email newsletter"
4. create a branch for the template
5. do NOT set the Subject field in the branch item
6. create an item from the branch

I would expect the subject would be the one from the standard values item, however it seems the branch field value is blank, and in turn the created item also has a blank subject field.

Should the Branch field value be that of the standard value. Or does the very act of creating a branch item eliminate any standard values you set.

Does the field versioing have any effect (e.g. Shared, Unversioned)?

I haven't been a big user of Branches, so I am surprised at the behaviour, but if it is normal, all good. Just want to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, if the template or standard values were locked when the branch or item was created, the standard values might not have carried through.

Either way, you need to reset the value of the sitecore item. On the item, click the 'Reset' button, which is under the Versions tab and check the checkbox next to 'Subject'. Now, the field will show as 'Subject [standard value]'.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You are correct .. I just tested the behaviour on a different instance of Sitecore, made sure there were no locks .. hey presto .. all good .. Standard values are carried through from Standard Values item, thru the branch template and pop-out the other end in the item, clearly marked 'standard value' .. now I need to go back and check the other environment and find out why no work.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the branch for the item template should copy the standard values and allow you to update the default values from the template.

So for example if you had "Monthly email newsletter" in the "Subject" field of the template it would be the same in the branch and all items created from that item.

Changing that field in the Standard Values should then update it in the branches and items.

If you have changed the field on the item however the link would be broken and you would no longer manage it from the standard values with out resetting the values.

Not sure on the shared/unversioned factor but dont think it effects the standard values.

Comment: hey phil! yeah thats what I would expect, but changing the standard values does not seem to be updating the branch value, or the item created from the branch value. wierd.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value in branch template, you've broken the link already. So after that if you change the standard value, the value in branch template will not effect

Comment: "5. do NOT set the Subject field in the branch item". 

The branch template "should" be using the standard value. However when I create the branch template, it doesn't use any standard values. It seems to have replaced them at time of creation with its own blank values.